# How to avoid overlapping of content in dockpanel

Tags: wpf

I have two stackpanel inside Dock Panel. When the window is resizing the top panel is overlapping the bottom one.

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" LastChildFill="True" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=characterLength}">

        <!-- Batch information panel: Top -->

        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="6,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="6,0,0,6" >

                <TextBlock x:Name="ReadOnlyNoBatchesTextBlock"  

                       DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                       Text="no batch" 
                       FontSize="19" HorizontalAlignment="left" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_NoBatches_Text"
                       FontWeight="Bold"

            />

                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="19" FontWeight="Bold" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchNumber_Text" />

                <TextBlock Text="status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"  
                       AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchSubmissionStatus_Text">

                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="submitted" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                       AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchSubmittedAt_Text">
                </TextBlock>

                <TextBlock Text="qeqweq" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchSubmittedBy_Text" />

                <TextBlock Text="ertert" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchProgressed_Text">
                </TextBlock>

                <TextBlock Text="dsdfgfdg" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchProgressedAt_Text" >

                </TextBlock>


                <!-- Must be last item in the stack panel otherwise you get a vertical gap-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="characterLength" Text="abcdefg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Hidden" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />
            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>
        <!-- Button panel: Bottom -->

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <!-- Content is set by a Style Trigger -->
            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,3" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_SetMarkerStandardised_Button" />

            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,3,0,3"  

                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_AllocateNextStandardisationBatch_Button" />

            <!-- Content, Automation Id & Command is set by a Style Trigger -->
            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,3" />

            <!-- Content is set by a Style Trigger -->
            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,3,0,3"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_AutoProgressBatches_Button" />

            <!-- Content is set by a Style Trigger -->
            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,3"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchListFilter_Button" />

            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,3"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_SubmitBatch_Button" />

            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,3,0,3" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_StartStop_Marker_Button">
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="a" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I need that when window is resizing bottom panel should always be visible and top panel will get scroll bar.

I have tried many ways but still getting the same issue from this code the top one will get the scroll bar but only when the bottom one will go invisible

Comment: If you want to keep the bottom panel always visible with it using as much space as it needs/wants, you should dock the bottom panel and let the othe panel fill the remaining space of the DockPanel unoccupied by the bottom panel. To do this layout properly, in your XAML put the bottom panel _before_ the other (variably sized) panel and let it dock at the bottom. Other observations: Why do you have this Grid there? All it contains is a DockPanel, so the Grid there is rather without purpose. Why are you trying to dock the DockPanel itself to the left side of a non-existing parent DockPanel?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
        <!--<ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="6,0,0,0">-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="6,0,0,6" >

                <TextBlock x:Name="ReadOnlyNoBatchesTextBlock"  

                           DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                           Text="no batch" 
                           FontSize="19" HorizontalAlignment="left" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_NoBatches_Text"
                           FontWeight="Bold"

                />

                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="19" FontWeight="Bold" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchNumber_Text" />

                <TextBlock Text="status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"  
                           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchSubmissionStatus_Text">

                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="submitted" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchSubmittedAt_Text">
                </TextBlock>

                <TextBlock Text="qeqweq" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchSubmittedBy_Text" />

                <TextBlock Text="ertert" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchProgressed_Text">
                </TextBlock>

                <TextBlock Text="dsdfgfdg" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchProgressedAt_Text" >

                </TextBlock>


                <!-- Must be last item in the stack panel otherwise you get a vertical gap-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="characterLength" Text="abcdefg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Hidden" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />
            </StackPanel>

        <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
        <!-- Button panel: Bottom -->

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <!-- Content is set by a Style Trigger -->
            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,3" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_SetMarkerStandardised_Button" />

            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,3,0,3"  

                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_AllocateNextStandardisationBatch_Button" />

            <!-- Content, Automation Id & Command is set by a Style Trigger -->
            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,3" />

            <!-- Content is set by a Style Trigger -->
            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,3,0,3"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_AutoProgressBatches_Button" />

            <!-- Content is set by a Style Trigger -->
            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,3"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_BatchListFilter_Button" />

            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,3"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_SubmitBatch_Button" />

            <Button Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,3,0,3" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DipIn_BatchReviewView_StartStop_Marker_Button">
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="a" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Avoid using ScrollViewer it will Avoid the Overlapping of the Content .

Comment: But I need scroll bar and I need that when the bottom panel is goes up while resizing the top one will get scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Grid` with two `RowDefinitions`:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" LastChildFill="True" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=characterLength}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="6,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="6,0,0,6" >
                ...
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```